GHC Warning: Non-exhaustive Pattern Match for List Despite Explicit Match on Empty List
I’m trying to write a simple Haskell function that distinguishes between an empty list and a non-empty list. Here’s my code:
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists, RebindableSyntax #-}

import Prelude (Int, IO, putStrLn)
import GHC.Exts (IsList (..))

doneVsItems :: [Int] -> IO ()
doneVsItems [] = putStrLn "Done"
doneVsItems (p:ps) = putStrLn "Items"

main :: IO ()
main = doneVsItems []

However, when I compile the code with -Werror=incomplete-patterns enabled, I get the following error:
error: [GHC-62161] [-Wincomplete-patterns, Werror=incomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘doneVsItems’:
        Patterns of type ‘[Int]’ not matched: []
  |
7 | doneVsItems [] = putStrLn "Done"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

I explicitly pattern match on both the empty list ([]) and the non-empty list ((p:ps)), so I don’t understand why GHC is saying the pattern match is non-exhaustive. What am I missing here?
It looks like OverloadedLists, and RebindableSyntax no longer work together. I've created an issue here.

What is the Show a => doing here?

Ok removed that. I tried Show a => [a] with no luck and forgot to remove the constraint.

but is the error still the same? I think the error originates from somewhere else (probably a few lines above).

Yes the error is still the same.

I tried to copy and paste your code on an online IDE (godbolt.org) and it worked fine, no warnings. I can only think of two possibilities: 1) you are manually entering the code in GHCi instead of loading it from a file (it does not look so in the error message, though -- it looks like you are using GHC properly); 2) you are compiling a different file from the one you posted.

I think you need to include more of your file. Make a copy of your file, and delete everything you can without changing the error, then show us that. As it stands, the code you've given doesn't cause the error you describe in 9.8.2 (at least not here). (And, indeed, if GHC behaved the way you describe in this question, I'd consider that a bug.)

It works fine. See here

@talex You forgot the -Werror=incomplete-patterns.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Doesn't change anything. See  here

@talex I don't know why tio.run isn't doing it, but when I add {-# OPTIONS -Werror=incomplete-patterns #-} to your onecompiler.com one, it reproduces.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Probably different version of compiler.

@talex Yep. I just checked, and this is a regression introduced in 8.6, and tio.run is still on 8.2.

This is a bug with GHC. The extensions OverloadedLists, and RebindableSyntax no longer work together. See steps to reproduce.

created an issue: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/25257

This is a very strange situation indeed, especially that it complains about missing the [] pattern and points to the [] pattern. But I have a guess: this definition is made inside a where clause, but only partially. For example, this code:
foo = () where
 doneVsItems [] = ()
doneVsItems (p:ps) = ()

produces these warnings:
test.hs:2:2: warning: [GHC-62161] [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘doneVsItems’:
        Patterns of type ‘[a]’ not matched: (_:_)
  |
2 |  doneVsItems [] = ()
  |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

test.hs:3:1: warning: [GHC-62161] [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘doneVsItems’:
        Patterns of type ‘[a]’ not matched: []
  |
3 | doneVsItems (p:ps) = ()
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Perhaps you accidentally copied and pasted part of one warning and part of another???
It is possible that the indentation of your two clauses may look the same but be considered different if your editor's tabstops are not set to 8 spaces, so if it looks okay by eye, one thing to check would be whether the tabs in the two lines match up.
